# Name of class in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, rename

i'm unable to rename my classes into iphone project in Xcode.
I've tried manually, and also by refactoring, renaming clicking with right button on class name in .h file.

I've this error message: "Unable to move filename to appname".

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the docs?  [XCode4 Transition Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Refactoring/Refactoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009984-CH8-SW5)